# The placement of participles defining the subject of the main clause

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, participles, redundancy

As far as I know, we can use participles right before or after the subject of the main clause to give extra information about the subject. For example:

> 1- ***Dressed in his class-A uniform***, the marine looked like a
>   recruitment poster. (Original)
>
> 1a- The marine, ***who was dressed in his class-A uniform***, looked
>   like a recruitment poster.
>
> 2- ***Glazed with barbecue sauce***, the rack of ribs lay nestled next
>   to a pile of sweet coleslaw. (Original)
>
> 2a- The rack of ribs, ***which are glazed with barbecue sauce***, lay
>   nestled next to a pile of sweet coleslaw.

---

But I have seen sentences that use participles at the end of the main clause with a comma or a colon to give extra information about the subject of the main clause.

When I want to give extra information about the subject of the main clause, ***can I just use this form (main clause + colon or comma + participles)*** ? Would that be okay?

For example:

> 3- The funeral is at 3.00, ***followed by a reception at Shaw's
>   bar***. (Original)
>
> 3a- The funeral is at 3.00 ***and will be followed by a reception at
>   Shaw's bar***.
>
> 3b- ***The funeral*** is at 3.00, ***which will be followed by a
>   reception at Shaw's bar.*** (I am not sure if this version is correct)

---

> 4- ***Essos*** is an immense landmass located to the east of Westeros,
>   ***extending into the far east of the known world***. (Original) (describes Essos)
>
> 4a- ***Essos*** is an immense landmass located to the east of Westeros
>   ***and Essos extends into the far east of the known world***.
>
> 4b- ***Essos*** is an immense landmass located to the east of Westeros
>   ***which extends into the far east of the known world***.

Comment: Is this an assignment of some sort?

Comment: No :). I am just trying to learn how it works.

Comment: You might find it more useful to "deconstruct" *The funeral is at 3.00, followed by a reception at Shaw's bar* as the "merging with deletion" of two statements: *The funeral is at 3.00. The funeral is followed by a reception at Shaw's bar.* I think that approach covers all your other examples: *The marine was dressed in his class-A uniform. The marine looked like a recruitment poster.* Sometimes we might want to explicitly convey the relationship between the two statements with a preposition: ***Because** he was dressed in his class-A uniform, the marine looked like a recruitment poster*.

Comment: Note that you ***can't*** delete the repeated subject from *That makes him very happy and says this* - it has to be *...and **he** says this.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. When I am allowed to use "merging with deletion" ? Is having the same subject in the main and participle clause enough to combine them into one sentence? +  The sentence four looks different from the other examples. The subject of the participle clause is different from the main clause in that sentence.

Comment: The syntax of participle clauses (both ***-ed*** and ***-ing*** verb forms) involves a lot of factors. Too much to even address in a single *Answer* on this site (even if I knew what to say) - certainly too much to cover in a comment. But I will just say here that I'm pretty sure there will be *few or **no*** contexts where you could validly include a ***semicolon*** with a parenthetical participle clause. And  that the initial participle clause in your first example could ALSO be placed after ***The marine*** OR at the end of the sentence, without needing anything like ***who was***.

Comment: This *seems* like it could be a duplicate of [Usage of past participles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216097/usage-of-past-participles), but it's not entirely clear. (Mainly because I'm not certain what this question is actually asking.)

Comment: @JasonBassford When I want to give extra information about the subject of the main clause, can I just use this form (main clause + colon or comma + participles) ? Would that be okay? + When I am allowed to use "merging with deletion" ? Is having the same subject in the main and participle clause enough to combine them into one sentence? +

Comment: @FumbleFingers + Is there a set of rules that guide me while I am trying to make those sentence into one combined sentence? or Is there a specific name for this reduction that I can look it up on the internet. I can't make these reduction easily even though I know participles. These are kind of different.

Comment: I think maybe you need to learn about [restrictive / non-restrictive relative clauses.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155232/) Consider, for example, *Snarling, the cat attacked the dog*, where if we move the first word to the *end* of the statement, it makes a difference whether we precede it by a comma (a *pause*, in the "real" language of speech). Be sure you understand that distinction first (it's much the same distinction as choosing to put the adjectival participle ***snarling*** immediately before ***cat***, or immediately before ***dog***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Snarling, the cat attacked the dog. (Snarling describes the cat) - The cat attacked the dog snarling. (I think here snarling describes  the cat again) - The cat attacked the dog, snarling (I think this one describes the dog but it is unclear) - The cat attacked the snarling dog. (Here describes the dog)

Comment: No. If the adjective comes at the *end*, there would ***normally be a comma*** before it, and it would "adverbially" describe *how* the cat attacked the dog (effectively, ***snarling*** applies to the cat). In the unusual case of there *not* being a comma / pause, that would mean we were identifying the specific dog that was snarling, with thre strong implication that there were *other* dogs who *weren't* snarling (which the cat *didn't* attack).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just commenting, not answering. Sorry that I don't have 50 reputation yet.
You may downvote me as you like.

This is wrong:

> That makes him very happy and says this: "..."

It should be

> That makes him very happy and **he** says this: "..."

Comment: Thanks, I have edited. But you could have just used comment button.

Comment: Actually, it's not wrong. It could also be saying *That makes him very happy and **[that]** says this.* The lack of the pronoun leaves the sentence ambiguous, but not ungrammatical. It would be a grammatically (if not stylistically) acceptable elision. (Dreams, or any thing or event, can be thought of as figuratively saying something.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: *This makes me very happy and says that I'm easily pleased!*